# Can I use these two inputs (GPIO) at the same time?

Tags: gpio

I realize this is a very specific question and its probably due to my lack of understanding of the GPIO pins...though I keep trying to understand. (I just must be dense)

I bought and have working the [16x2 LCD from adafruit](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16x2-character-lcd-plus-keypad-for-raspberry-pi). It connects to the Pi via the header on the LCD.
I want to buy and use the [adafruit ultimate GPS](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2012/08/28/adafruit-ultimate-gps-on-a-raspberry-pi/) with it (all 3 pieces at the same time).

Is it possible to use both devices at the same time? I can't find exactly what pins are required by each on the Pi. Ideally they'd use different pins and I could wire connect the two pieces. If anyone knows what pins they use, and they require the same ones in the Pi board, can you point me at some reading or hardware that I'd need to achieve this?

I'm not really interested in a USB receiver. I'd like to go with one from the GPIO pins.

I've come across [this post](http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=38538) which explains what pins the LCD connect to on the Pi board. But looking at the GPIO diagrams I don't understand what pins this relates to. The only thing I've found on the GPS [is here,](https://raw.github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MTK3329-GPS-Module-Test-Sketch/master/Adafruit_MTK3329_GPS_Test.pde) but am unsure if this is related to the Pi, if so, what Pi pins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use a stacking header http://www.adafruit.com/products/1112 so that you can access the pins needed for the GPS. Then, you need to connect the GPS up to the GPIO. Use the guide here: http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-on-the-raspberry-pi/using-uart-instead-of-usb

Basically, the LCD uses the I2C bus (which is two pins plus ground and power) and the GPS uses the UART pins (two pins) and ground and power.

If you've already soldered a non-stacking header onto the LCD board, you will need to de-solder it before putting the stacking header on.

Comment: Thanks. What's the reason for the stacking header? So the pins go up higher than the LCD board and I have something to connect the GPS too? Could I use male to female for the pi>LCD and female to female cables for pi> GPS?